# What can cause a LazyInitatializationException whereas Spring Open In View is enabled?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am analysing a "classic" Hibernate error :

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException : could not initialize proxy – no Session.`

I am wondering how it could happen whereas the Spring Open In View mode is enabled?

If you have any documentation or knowledge on a possible reason, please share.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are some feebacks on my context, and an example of what could cause `LazyInitializationException` event if Spring Open In View is enabled.

**Context**

My application is a REST API server developed with Spring Boot 2.5.3.
Spring Open In View is kept enabled by default.
A lot of Services are annotated with `@Transactional` methods.
Spring-data is used, and `Entitymanager` too, to create some native queries.

**The error**

One REST API request, that generates a lot requests to the database (both selections and insertions), fails with `LazyInitializationException`.

**Debugging**

By setting a breakpoint when `LazyInitializationException` is thrown, I discovered that the exception is thrown in `org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer#initialize`, because the `session` is null. Then I discovered that the `session` is set to null, when the method `EntityManager.clear` is called. For any reason I don't know, this method was explicitely called in the code.

**Fixing**

So I just removed the call to `EntityManager.clear`, and the request works. I'm still wondering why previous developers wanted to clear the `EntityManager`, probably because they were confused with the transaction management.

**Conclusion**

Even in Spring Open In View is enabled, and as a result, event if a Hibernate Session is opened, calling `EntityManager.clear` unset the session to the entities loaded before. Then trying to access a Lazy Loaded field on those entities throws `LazyInitializationException`.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Sometime one clears the entity manager to reduce the memory footprint of the hibernate first level cache, or because a batch update invalidating most of the cached entities has been executed, and one prefers to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html) from the latest hibernate version.

As you can see

> Indicates an attempt to access not-yet-fetched data outside of a
> session context. For example, when an uninitialized proxy or
> collection is accessed after the session was closed.

Most probably somewhere you read some entity and then outside of a transaction you try to read some collection which was by default lazy loaded. So then another request needs to be done to database, but since you are out of transaction you receive this exception.

This usually occurs in case you load an entity without the annotation `@Transactional` or some other configuration to load it inside a transaction and then you give this to your `controller` to be returned to the user. Then the controller will use `jackson` or some other library to convert the `entity` object into a `json` and will try to read any field. At this point trying to read any lazy loaded collections from the entity, will result in this exception since the read will be outside of a transaction.

Comment: OK but Spring Open In View is enabled, so my controller should always run in a dedicated session... am I wrong?

Comment: you mean `http-session`. This is different than `database-transaction-session`. Try to add to the failing controller the annotation `@Transactional`. It will probably fix the issue. Please also accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: No, I'm speaking about this property : spring.jpa.open-in-view=true (by default) in spring boot. Well explained here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view

Comment: @GuillaumeDelafosse In this case I would try to step in with debug and use the https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistry.html to verify that the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` is correctly registered or something is malfunctioning in between.

Comment: @GuillaumeDelafosse, if you can use debug mode, step also in `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` to check when the session is created and closed, and set a break point on `LazyInitializationException` to check if it is thrown outside the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` hibernate session lifecycle.